# Denying everyone access to a folder, except an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I am working on the website for a company which develops iPhone apps.  One of our apps needs to regularly access a folder on our server (hosted by HawkHost) to update information, and I've figured out how to do that.

What I would like to do is somehow set the permissions for the folder so that only this app can access it and every copy of the app can access it, but all other requests get denied.

Comment: [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)?

Answer (score 2):

About the best you could do would be to intercept every request to access the resource and then, based on the request, you could allow or deny the request. You will need some sort of RSA-style access token exchange (similar to how SSL does it) to ensure that it's only your applications making the request.

In general, however, this sort of resource access is not particularly secure, since *anyone* can make a request and can pretend to be your app. That is why an SSL-style handshake would be needed that uses some in-app key that your server can use to determine that the requesting agent is, in fact, one of your apps, and the same is true of the server so that the app can verify that it is, in fact, the correct server (to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks).

Ultimately, you can't do this with just a folder and need a much more substantial security framework in place to do what you are after. Security is hard.